# Load library error in Matlab

Tags: matlab, loadlibrary

I am trying to use `loadlibrary` in MATLAB by importing the qliblibrary header file but when I use the load library command:

```
loadlibrary('qlib','qlib.h')
```

I get following error:

> Error using loadlibrary
>       Failed to preprocess the input file.
>        Output from preprocessor is:C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017a\extern\examples\Legacy_code\qlib.h:168:7: error: #error
>        unsupported compiler/os combination
>             #error unsupported compiler/os combination

This is the qlib header file  where I am getting the compiler error:

```
#pragma message ("used compiler:   CVI LabWindows C")

    #define QLIB_WIN_32
    #define QAPICALLER _stdcall

    #ifndef FAR 
      #define FAR
    #endif   

    #ifndef WORD
        #define WORD unsigned short  
    #endif

    #pragma message ("destination OS:  Windows 9x / NT / 2000 / XP")
    #pragma message ("executable type: CVI")

#elif defined (__GNUC__)                                                /* gcc (on Linux) */

    #define FAR
    #define far

    #ifdef __unix__
        #define QLIB_LINUX
        #define QAPICALLER

    #else
        #error unsupported compiler/os combination
    #endif

#else

    #error unsupported compiler detected                                /* unknown compiler */

#endif
```

Comment: Please share qlib.h

Comment: I think your gcc compile version is not match with your code.

Comment: I agree with Dr. Geek plz share qlib.h